# Populate dynamically rendered form fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am having 3 materialUI TextFields which are render n number of times (n is an integer input from the user before rendering the form field, where I stored it in a variable named groupMembersCount).
I am getting it dynamically rendered by this way:

```
export default function DynamicGroupMember() {
    const [groupMembersCount, setGroupMembersCount] = useState(0);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = useState([
        {fullName: "", phoneNo: "", gender: ""},
    ]);
  function handleChange(event, index) {
        console.log(event.target.value, index);
        let newArr = [...groupDetails]; // copying the old datas array
        let item = newArr[index];
        item = {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
        newArr[index] = item;

        setGroupDetails(newArr);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Number of Group: <TextField name="groupMembersCount" onChange={(event) => {
            setGroupMembersCount(event.target.value)
        }}/>
            {Array.apply(null, {length: groupMembersCount}).map(
                (e, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <strong>Member #{i + 1}</strong>
                        <div className="getIndex" name={i + 1}>
                            <TextField
                                id={`name${i + 1}`}
                                name="fullName"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Name"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id={`phoneNo${i + 1}`}
                                name="phoneNo"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Mobile Number"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            />
                            <Select
                                id={`gender${i + 1}`}
                                name="gender"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Gender"
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            >
                                <option value="MALE">Male</option>
                                <option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
                                <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                            </Select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
            <Button onClick={() => {
                setShow(true)
            }}>Show</Button>
            {
                show ?
                    groupDetails.map(member =>
                        <Card>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                {member.fullName}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {member.phoneNo}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary">
                                {member.gender}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>) : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

What if I filled the number (**groupMembersCount**) and then filled those form fields and after filling, I modified **groupMembersCount** (*either increase or decrease*), in case of increase I want the values that user filled should retain and if decreased, form fields values should clear out.
I tried passing values from groupDetails array to form in "value" prop but it shows an error because the index I an writing/passing the values initially doesn't exist at that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set value from `groupDetails` that was stored before using `useState`. Please check this example:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function DynamicGroupMember3() {
    const [groupMembersCount, setGroupMembersCount] = useState(0);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState([]);
    const [showState, setShowState] = useState(false);
    const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = useState([
        {fullName: "", phoneNo: "", gender: ""},
    ]);
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        idProof: "",
        noOfPeople: "",
        bookingId: "",
        detailsOfPeople: [],
    });

    function handleChange(event, index) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(errorText.length, 'length');
        if (event.target.name === "phoneNo") {
            // do validation here
            let valid = false;
            if (isNaN(event.target.value)) {
                let arr = [...errorText];
                arr[index] = 'Invalid ' + event.target.name;
                setErrorText(arr);
            } else {
                let arr = [...errorText];
                arr[index] = '';
                setErrorText(arr);
            }
        }

        let newArr = [...groupDetails]; // copying the old datas array
        let item = newArr[index];
        item = {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
        newArr[index] = item;
        setGroupDetails(newArr);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Number of Group: <TextField name="groupMembersCount" onChange={(event) => {
            if (isNaN(event.target.value)) {
                alert('Please enter number');
                return;
            }
            if (event.target.value !== '') {
                let noOfMember = parseInt(event.target.value);
                let errors = new Array(noOfMember);
                setErrorText(errors);
                if (groupMembersCount > noOfMember) {
                    let newGroup = [];
                    groupDetails.map((group, index) => {
                        if (index < noOfMember) {
                            newGroup.push(group);
                        }
                    });
                    setGroupDetails(newGroup);
                }
                setGroupMembersCount(noOfMember);
            }
        }}/>
            {Array.apply(null, {length: groupMembersCount}).map(
                (e, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <strong>Member #{i + 1}</strong>
                        <div className="getIndex" name={i + 1}>
                            <TextField
                                id={`name${i + 1}`}
                                name="fullName"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Name"
                                value={groupDetails[i] ? groupDetails[i].fullName : ''}
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id={`phoneNo${i + 1}`}
                                name="phoneNo"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Mobile Number"
                                value={groupDetails[i] ? groupDetails[i].phoneNo : ''}
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                                error={errorText[i] !== '' && errorText[i] !== undefined}
                                helperText={errorText[i]}
                            />
                            <Select
                                id={`gender${i + 1}`}
                                name="gender"
                                variant="outlined"
                                margin="none"
                                label="Gender"
                                value={groupDetails[i] ? groupDetails[i].gender : ''}
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event, i)
                                }}
                            >
                                <option value="MALE">Male</option>
                                <option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
                                <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                            </Select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
            <Button onClick={() => {
                setShow(true)
            }}>Show</Button>
            {
                show ?
                    groupDetails.map((member, index) =>
                        <Card key={index}>
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                    {member.fullName}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                                    {member.phoneNo}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography color="textSecondary">
                                    {member.gender}
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>) : null
            }
            <Button onClick={() => {
                console.log(groupDetails, 'groupDetails');
                setState({
                    idProof: "XYZ123",
                    noOfPeople: groupDetails.length,
                    bookingId: "boking-4434",
                    detailsOfPeople: groupDetails
                });
                console.log(groupDetails, 'groupDetails');
                setShowState(true);

            }}>Show STATE</Button>
            {
                showState ?
                    <Card>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                Id Proof: {state.idProof}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                                No Of People: {state.noOfPeople}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary">
                                Booking Id: {state.bookingId}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card> : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What if I decreased the "groupMembersCount" after filling the detail, how to empty that "groupDetails" array?

Comment: When you decrease `groupMembersCount` then it automatically removes row

Comment: When I decrease it shows me rows with the updated values, but the values which were previously saved are printing in console i.e. values at that index are not set to null.

Comment: hi I have updated my answer for decreasing. Please check

Comment: I have a similar situation, but I need to add validations, lets say for name. How would I trigger the validations in that component exclusively? https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sound-mvbqt?file=/src/App.js